# determining the function when its poles and and residue is given.

Tags: complex-analysis

Q) the only singularity of a single valued function f(z) are poles of order 2 and 1 at Z=1 and Z=2 with residues of these poles 1 and 3 respectively.if f(0)=3/2 and f(-1)=1, determine the function f(z).

ITS AN ASSIGNMENT PROBLEM,I HAVE UNDERSTOOD POLES AND THIER ORDER,BUT AM UNABLE TO UNDERSTAND IDEA OF RESIDUE AND f(0)  and  f(-1) in the above problem.
i tried searching on the internet,but couldnt find a relavent question same as mine..

and i was self teaching myself,this is what i managed.

1. the poles and their order is given by.

### 1

(Z-1)^2(Z-2)

could you help me with complete solution of this problem .

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $f(z)=\frac{Az^2+Bz+Γ}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}+Δz$

Then $Res(f,2)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 2}(z-2)f(z)=4A+2B+Γ$ , so $4A+2B+Γ=3$.

Also, $Res(f,1)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}[(z-1)^2f(z)]'=-(3Α+2Β+Γ)$, so $3Α+2Β+Γ=-1$.

Use $f(0), f(-1)$ and make sure that your nominator doesn't factorize with $z-1$ or $z-2$, to keep the orders of the poles as given.

Obviously though, this is not the only function with the given properties.